# Custom Object ID into a field?

Tags: custom-object, custom-field, salesforce-id

I'm new to using Salesforce, but I need the ID of my custom object e.g. a054J0000057Ps8QAE to show in a Custom Field, is this possible?

I'm guessing there's maybe a formal I need to add in the Default Value on the custom field - but I'm not sure what it is.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Why do you need a custom field? Why can't your application access the `Id` field, which will always be the records id?

Comment: I'm using 123FormBuilder, which will prefill data. But I have to run a check to prefill the data, if the id outputted on my form is the same as the id on the custom object then prefill the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a custom formula field of type string and formula will be record Id
[image]

Refer the screenshot

Comment: When I 'Choose the field type' the only relevant one I could choose is text? Then when I'm on the details page and in the 'Default Value' box I cannot add: $Record.ID it just gives me an error.

Comment: Click on insert and chose the required field in the formula. In the above screenshot I have considered for contact